# MVC - Div class not showing background image or colour in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a background image to one and colour to another div class using css style. However the image is not showing at all, not sure what the problem is..

HTML:

```
@{
  ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_DefaultLayout.cshtml";
}

<div class="parralax">    
</div>

<div class="home-parralax-sub-section">    
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.parralax {
background: url(../../../../images/Resources/MainImage2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.home-parralax-sub-section{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Now if I add the image or colour directly to the div like that:

```
<div class="parralax" style="height: 500px; color: red;">    
</div>

<div class="home-parralax-sub-section" style="height: 1000px;">
    <img src="~/images/Resources/MainImage.jpg" />
</div>
```

It will work!

Any help would be appricated, thanks :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```css
.parralax {
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 150px;
  /*Add to this div height*/
}

.home-parralax-sub-section {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parralax">
</div>

<div class="home-parralax-sub-section">
</div>
```

Add height to div containing the background-image

Comment: #facepalm its so obvious now! height in the .parralax!. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add height to .parallax class then it will work.

```
.parralax {
background: url('../../../../images/Resources/MainImage2.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
   height:500px;
}

.home-parralax-sub-section{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```